# Windows Authentication for winforms with Windows 2000

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-authentication, windows-2000

I use the following code to validate users through windows authentication for my winform application.  This works fine with windows XP but when the user is using windows 2000, it says that the userid or password is in valid.

How do I do this in Windows 2000.  Further, How do I detect whether the user is using Windows Xp or windows 2000.

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string userName, string domainName, string password, int LogonType, int LogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    public bool IsValidateCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        IntPtr tokenHandler = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool isValid = LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 2, 0, ref tokenHandler);
        return isValid;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You should probably pass `3`, not `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation for `LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **Windows 2000**:  If you need to validate
>   credentials, use the SSPI APIs. For
>   information about using the SSPI APIs,
>   see [How To Validate User Credentials
>   on Microsoft Operating Systems](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=87260). Use
>   the `LogonUser` or `LogonUserEx` function
>   if you need to impersonate the user by
>   using the returned access token and
>   access a resource.

To check what version of Windows you're running on, check [`Environment.OSVersion.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx).

Windows 2000 is 5.0; XP is 5.2.

Also, you *need* to close the handle by calling [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the links... The sample code in your second link, is just a bouncer for me... I think it is VC++, on which I'm 0...  Do I need to try converting the whole stuff or is there an easy way to do it in C#...

Comment: Yes; that's C++.  I don't have time now to convert it to C#.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do it in C#; you'll need to convert that code sample.